# how to test if i have the last option of a select is selected

Tags: jquery

helo everyone in my case i want to add a test to see if the last option of the select was selected or not

this is my select :

```
<select class="select" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
        options: addressOptions,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        value: selectedAddress,
        event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};
    "><option value="">adress 1</option><option value=""> adresse2</option><option value=""> Adresse 3</option><option value=""> Adresse4</option>
<option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select elements last text and compare with selected option's text

```js
function test(el) {
    let lastValue = $(el).find('option').last().text();
    let selectedValue = $('option:selected', el).text();
    
    console.log(lastValue, selectedValue, lastValue === selectedValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" onChange="test(this)" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
        options: addressOptions,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        value: selectedAddress,
        event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};
    ">
  <option value="">adress 1</option>
  <option value=""> adresse2</option>
  <option value=""> Adresse 3</option>
  <option value=""> Adresse4</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

Comment: would it not be easier to do it like `$("option:last",el).is(":selected")`